# Doctrine - Postgresql database driver Uncaught exception

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-odm, doctrine-query

i' m trying to setting up CodeIgniter - Doctrine with Postgresql database.

I've changed the $db['default']['dbdriver'] to 'pgsql', following the instructions at

http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup

but i have an issue, the message i get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException' with message  'Unknown record property / related component "example" on "Airports"' in  C:\wamp\www\ci_doctrine_day1\system\application\plugins\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\Record\Filter\Standard.php on line 44

and also

> Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException: Unknown record property / related component "example" on "Airports" in C:\wamp\www\ci_doctrine_day1\system\application\plugins\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\Record\Filter\Standard.php on line 44

i have a table called "Airports" and a collumn "example" but i can't access my database. Keep in mind that i made it with mySql database pretty well. I don't know what to do guys and i spend my all day for this. Any assistance would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

P.S: 
i'm using

- wamp server 2.1
- Apache Version : 2.2.17
- Php Version : 5.3.5
- Postgresql Version : 9.1